# Image Registration by Manual marking of corresponding points using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, affinetransform, homography, perspectivecamera

1. I have a **processed binary image** of **dimension 300x300**. This processed image contains few object(person or vehicle).

[image: processed binary image]

2. I also have another **RGB image** of the same scene of **dimensiion 640x480**. It is **taken from a different position**

[image]

**note : both cameras are not the same**

I can detect objects to some extent in the first image using background subtraction. **I want to detect corresponding objects in the 2nd image**. I went through opencv functions

- [getAffineTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getAffineTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst%29)
- [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getPerspectiveTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst%29)
- [findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat%20findHomography%28InputArray%20srcPoints,%20InputArray%20dstPoints,%20int%20method,%20double%20ransacReprojThreshold,%20OutputArray%20mask%29)
- [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform)

All these functions require corresponding points(coordinates)  in two images

In the 1st binary image, I have only the information that an object is present,it does not have features exactly similar to second image(RGB).

I thought conventional feature matching to determine corresponding control points which could be used to estimate the transformation parameters is **not feasible** because I think I cannot determine and match features from binary and RGB image(am I right??).

If I am wrong,  what features could I take, how should I proceed with Feature matching, find corresponding points, estimate the transformation parameters.

**The solution which I tried more of Manual marking to estimate transformation parameters**(please correct me if I am wrong)

**Note : There is no movement of both cameras.**

- Manually marked rectangles around objects in processed image(binary)
- Noted down the coordinates of the rectangles
- Manually marked rectangles around objects in 2nd RGB image
- Noted down the coordinates of the rectangles
- Repeated above steps for different samples of 1st binary and 2nd RGB images

Now that I have some 20 corresponding points, I used them in the function as :

> findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, 0) ;

So once I detect an object in 1st image,

- I drew a bounding box around it,
- Transform the coordinates of the vertices using the above found transformation,
- finally draw a box in 2nd RGB image with **transformed coordinates as vertices**.

  But this doesnt mark the box in 2nd RGB image exactly over the person/object. Instead it is drawn somewhere else. Though I take several sample images of binary and RGB and use several corresponding points to estimate the transformation parameters, it seems that they are not accurate enough..

What are the meaning of CV_RANSAC and CV_LMEDS option, ransacReprojecThreshold and how to use them?

Is my approach good...what should I modify/do to make the registration accurate?

Any alternative approach to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to OpenCV myself, but my suggestions would be:

- Seeing as you have the objects identified in the first image, I shouldn't think it would be hard to get keypoints and extract features? (or maybe you have this already?)
- Identify features in the 2nd image
- Match the features using OpenCV `FlannBasedMatcher` or similar
- Highlight matching features in 2nd image or whatever you want to do.

I'd hope that because all your features in the first image should be positives (you know they are the features you want), then it'll be relatively straight forward to get accurate matches.

Like I said, I'm new to this so the ideas may need some elaboration.

Comment: Thank you Mike... The 1st image is not an RGB image...Its a grayscale image in which I detect objects...It is a binary image now.. Also Feature matching requires good and approximately exact features in both images...Since 1st image is grayscale(aftr processing->binary) and 2nd img is RGB, I thought feature matching might not give proper results.. It wont match at all(you can see how object in 1st img is inaccurate to the shape in 2nd img)

Comment: Fair point, what's the actual result that you're looking for? I'm not sure I understood the question.

Comment: I want to track the corresponding objects which I detect in 1st img in the 2nd RGB image...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late to answer this and the asker might not see this, but if the 1st image is originally a grayscale then this could be done:

1.) 2nd image ----> grayscale  ------> gray2ndimg

2.) Point to Point correspondences b/w gray1stimg and gray2ndimg by matching features.